# Why does ESLint throw parsing error while defining async function as method to existing object and how to prevent it?

Tags: javascript, async-await, eslint, ecmascript-2017

Let's assume we have plain object

```
const foo = {}
```

and by using Promise constructor syntax we would add async method to it this way:

```
foo.myAsyncMethod = function () {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    ...
  })
}
```

but we can't do this (according to ESlint):

```
foo.myAsyncMethod = async function() {
  ...
}
```

what is convenient approach to add new async functions to objects as method properties after object is already declared?

Comment: You can not access the original object being created?

Comment: @dewwwald Nope, it's just ESLint parsing error, please see answer below for more info.

Comment: I know that. That is why I am asking. I was bussy writing an answer. So if you have access to the object creation that would make it obvious. See potential solution below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears syntax from question is actually legit:

```
const obj = {}

obj.foo = function () {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    resolve(1)
  })
}

obj.bar = async function () {
  return await Promise.resolve(2)
}

obj.foo().then(context => console.log(context))

obj.bar().then(context => console.log(context))
```

Produces:

```
1
2
```

I got cofused by it because of ESLint giving me error:

[image]

In addition, to fix parsing errors from ESLint, add this to your `babelrc` file:

```
"parserOptions": {
  "ecmaVersion": 2017
}
```

Comment: worked on my end too !